# Find non white-spaces from DisplayName attribute

Tags: powershell

My question is :  how to find users none whitespace before parentheses like below ?

```
Display name :  John Wick(IT Engineeer)
```

Normally , I can find users more than one whitespace before parentheses.

```
Get-ADUser -filter * -Properties DisplayName | ? {$_.DisplayName -match "\s{2,}\("}
```

Comment: You are looking for [RegEx with a negative lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the regex to this:

```
"[^\s]+\("
```

This will find any user name that does not (`^`) have whitespace (`\s`) in front of the bracket.  Obviously, this assumes all users have names like: `User Name (Department)`